# Can I play Minecraft PE with bluetooth?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Me and my sibling want to play Minecraft together. Is there a way to use Bluetooth instead of WiFi to get connected? If so, how? We have MCPE version 15.0.

Answer (score 3):

You can't play multiplayer with Bluetooth.

Most devices nowadays support hosting a Wifi access point, one can host and other can connect and you can play together that way.